# Issues adjusting space in LyX when generating sticker labels using package labels

Tags: lyx

I am trying to make stickers labels with LyX using the package "labels".

The LyX file is here:
[LyX input file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B28kjtGCcBiodlI4b0VVMGVkZ1U)

And the result is:

[image: PDF output from LyX]

They do not fit well in the space, so I am trying to adjust them. The one in the left has a big inter line space. I have tried to remove it but it is impossible Where is that option?. In addition, I tried to centre the first line, but all of them are centred. How can I mark each of the lines as an independent block?

Regarding the label in the right, although it does not fit the label, it is more adjusted. However, for example, the line containing "Best before: 16/12/16" should continue with "Amount: 100 gr ...", that is, there should  not be a new line. Is there anything I that I am missing? FIXED. See below.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

FIX for the line breaks in label on the right: set Tools→Preferences→Output→General→Output line length to 0